# When I delete a data in firebase, it is deleted from the database, but it is not deleted from the list without going to another activity

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm listing Firebase user's favorite words. When the user presses the favButton, it will remove the favorite word. The favorite word is deleted in the database. But the favorite list is not updated immediately and the deleted word is still in the list. When I come back from another activity, it is deleted. How can I solve this? The place where I deleted the favorite word is in the adapter.

```
class DeleteFavorite: AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    database = Firebase.database.reference

}

 fun deleteFav(keyKelime: String?) {

    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    val userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
    val refFavori = database.getReference("/users/${userId}/favorites/${keyKelime}")

    refFavori.removeValue().addOnSuccessListener {
        Log.e("unfav","Fav geri alındı")
    }

 }
```

My adapter

```
 holder.favButton.setOnClickListener {

        if (!isClicked) {
            holder.favButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border)

            val deleteFavorite = DeleteFavorite()
            deleteFavorite.deleteFav(kelime.keyKelime)
        } else {
            isClicked = true

            val detayActivity = DetayActivity()
            detayActivity.writeNewFav(kelime?.keyKelime.toString())
            holder.favButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_dark)
        }
    }
```

And my FavoriteWords

```
    fun tumFavoriler(kelimelerListe: ArrayList<Kelimeler>, rvFav:RecyclerView){

    adapter = KelimelerAdapter(layoutInflater.context,newKelimelerList)//bura kelime istiyoo


    rvFav.adapter = adapter
    
    refFavoriler.get().addOnSuccessListener {

        for( c in it.children){
            val favKelimeId = c.child("kelime_id").value
            kelimelerListe.forEach {
                if (it.kelime_id == favKelimeId){

                    newKelimelerList.add(it)
                    Log.e("it","$newKelimelerList")

                }
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }.addOnFailureListener{

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you use `get()` to read the data from the database, which (as this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once) says) reads the value only once.

If you want your app to respond to changes in the database, use a realtime listener as shown in the documentation section on [reading data with a realtime listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_with_persistent_listeners).

Comment: I edited the code above. I removed get and changed it to addvaluelistener. but there is something wrong. Still not what I wanted.

Comment: Please don't change your question like that. In your original code you used `get()` which explains why you didn't receive any updates. By changing that in your question, the Q&A now no longer makes sense and is not useful for future visitors.

Comment: "there is something wrong" is hard to help with. I recommend running the code in a debugger, setting a breakpoint inside `onDataChange` and checking if you reach that breakpoint after the change. If so, step through the code to see if it does what you expect it to do. Does `newKelimelerList` have the contents you expect it to have by the time you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't think of that. I'm fixing now

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to changes within the database as Frank mentioned, but you                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              might not be interested in real-time updates as managing changing data can be difficult.

As an alternative, you can assume the data is successful on completion and update it locally, such as removing the item by index or key properties updating it locally.
This is a practice known as "Positive Assumptions".

This process does use the same logic you would with a snapshot listener, but it won't fire off changes until the user does a specific task.